How to retrieve sync'd photos and videos from an iPhone?
I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 15.7.1.
On that device I have some photos taken with that device, which I can easily back up / transfer to other devices and so on -- just adding this note, so it is clear that I know how to back up / transfer regular iPhone photos.
Now, there are also other photos there, which were transferred there by means of a "sync" operation -- copied from some old Mac basically. They appear in the "Photos" app as "From My Mac".
I do not see them in "Image Capture" when the iPhone is connected to a Mac.
I would like to get those pictures (and videos) from the iPhone. The iPhone is the only storage I still have those pictures on and I want to retrieve them from there.
How can I do it?

Does this help?

I am not even sure if those photos would be backed up. But even if they would, it would only allow me to move them to another iPhone, whereas I want the photo/video files on the Mac. [iPhone backup stored on a Mac is kind of a binary dump with no access to individual files]

I have a vague recollection that there were "other options" offered in the backup - something that would have provided access to the files - but don't recall details. Apologies
